# Search An ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What is the most efficient way to search for a single element in an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`? Given the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(3);
b.add(4);
intList.add(a);
intList.add(b);
```

How would I search to see if the `ArrayList` `intList` contains a specific `Integer`, like `3`?

Comment: no efficient solution that i can think of. maybe if you described the bigger problem a more efficient data structure could be found?

Comment: Is looping over the whole 2-d array efficient enough?

Comment: [The ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477442/algorithm-efficient-way-to-search-an-integer-in-a-two-dimensional-integer-array) will probably help

Comment: @Mureinik Apparently. That's why I asked.

Comment: You can try looping through main list and using `contains()` method in inner `ArrayList`.

Comment: That question is totally different from this one. It asks for a way to look into a matrix (not a list of lists) which respects certain criterias, like increasing monotonically.

Comment: It will need `O(n ^ 2)` if there is no sequence hasn't already maintained. Now, defined what do you mean by efficient: time cost or shorter approach(<-- some people asks for this too)?

Comment: Are the `List<Integer>`s sorted?  If so, then you can at least do a binary search on each one to improve performance.

Comment: @rob: nope, but you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: @MemLeak how do you know they aren't sorted?  Unless I missed something, there isn't anything in the question or comments to suggest that they are not sorted.

Comment: @rob: I think i missunderstoud your question, i though you mean a sorting like a Hash-Based Collection will do. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterates trough all the lists and ask if any of them contain your value.

```
public boolean contains(int x, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists) {
    for (ArrayList list: listOfLists) {
        if (list.contains(x)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I agree with radai. There is probably the need for a more efficient data structure rather than an efficient algorithm

Comment: Thanks. I agree I can make a more efficient data structure, but in a pinch, this is fine. Wasn't sure if there was a function I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Adam_G for the general case where the lists of integers are unsorted, this is the best you can do.  However, if each `List<Integer>` happens to be populated with a monotonically increasing sequence as shown in your example, you can improve performance from O(n^2) to O(n log n).  And if no two `List<Integer>`s have overlapping ranges (again, as in your example), you can improve your search performance to O(log n).