# sorted matrix search master theorem analysis

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

So the problem is to find whether x is in one of the elements of a sorted matrix ascending by row and by column.

example :

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

I'm interested to find the time complexity of the divide and conquer solution of this problem. I've googled it but i've found only for the O(m+n) solution, and also from this [Search a sorted 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316246/search-a-sorted-2d-matrix). but he says(comment on answer) that "T(R) = 3T(R/4)", why is the f(R) = 0 ?

The question is what is the complexities of the divide and conquer solution using master theorem ? 
and in T(R) = 3T(R/4) + f(R), what should be the f(R) ?

if it helps, this is my divide and conquer solution :

```
bool find_x_in_matrix(int x, int mat[3][3], int top_row, int top_col, int bot_row, int bot_col) {
if(top_row > bot_row || top_col > bot_col)
    return false;

int mid_row = (bot_row + top_row) / 2;
int mid_col = (bot_col + top_col) / 2;

if(mat[mid_row][mid_col] == x)
    return true;
else if(mat[mid_row][mid_col] > x) {
    return find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, top_row, mid_col, mid_row - 1, bot_col) ||
        find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, top_row, top_col, mid_row-1, mid_col-1) || 
        find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, mid_row, top_col, bot_row, mid_col-1);
}else if(mat[mid_row][mid_col] < x) {
    return find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, top_row, mid_col + 1, mid_row, bot_col) || 
        find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, mid_row + 1, top_col, bot_row, mid_col) || 
        find_x_in_matrix(x, mat, mid_row + 1, mid_col + 1, bot_row, bot_col);       
}
}
```

edit to clarify solution :

algorithm : 
1. compare the middle element of the matrix to the search value
2. if the value equals m(i,j) return true
3. if the value is smaller, search the value in top right, top left, bottom left of matrix
4. if the value is larger, search the value in top right, bottom right, bottom left of the matrix

Comment: What s top_row, top_col, etc. Can you give psuedo code instead of actual code.. thanks

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal , i've edited my question. to further clarify my solution. top_row is the index of top most row of matrix to be examined for value x, and the same goes for top_col etc

Comment: f(n) is the cost to merge the pieces.  shouldn't T(R) be T(n)?

Comment: @thang by T(R) it means R = mxn (m is the maximum row and n is the maximum column), i've changed f(n) to f(R) though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this right, but i'm using case 2 of the master theorem

T(R) = 3T(R/4) + theta(1)

f(R) = theta(1) = theta(R) = theta(R^(log4(3)))

f(R) = theta(R^(log4(3))) = theta(R^(log4(3)) * logk(R)) is true with k = 0, so the time complexity is :

T(R) = theta(R^(log4(3)) * log(R)) = theta(R^0.8 * log(R))

Comment: Why is it case 2? We can use case 2 if c = Theta(n^(0.8)) - Can we prove that?

Comment: @smk case 2 requirement is f(R) = theta((R^c ) * (log(R))^k) where c = logb a is true for some constant k>=0. 

well, as you can see from the second row in my post (f(R) = theta(1) = theta(R) = theta(R^(log4(3))))

theta(R^log4(3)) == theta((R^c) * (log(R))^k) with k = 0

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence relation

```
T(R) = 3T(R/4) + c
```

is clear because in every step, you are discarding 1/4th of the search space and looking at rest of the 1/4th of space 3 times .

According to wiki, 
f (n) is the cost of the work done outside the recursive calls, which includes the cost of dividing the problem and the cost of merging the solutions to the subproblems.

I think this is just a constant. f(n) may not be zero but it is definitely a constant value and doesnt depend on the search space.

EDIT:

Im not sure how to use the Master Theorem for this but if we unroll the recurrence relation
we get

```
 T(n) = 3^2* T(n/(4^2)) + c(1 + 3)
```

Going ahead, `T(n) = 3^k * T(n/4^k) + c(3^0 + 3^1 ... + 3^(k-1))`

This is where I am stuck..Can we reduce the RHS ? Forgotten my high school math.

I stand to be corrected though.

Comment: and what should be the time complexity of the above solution using master theorem? because that's the main question. thanks anyway

Comment: is it really that *you are discarding 1/4th of the search space and looking at rest of the 3/4th*?  I thought it's more like you're looking at 1/4 of the search space 3 times.

Comment: maybe, but not necessarily... you can't tell that from the equation.

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal, maybe you can explain more how do you get the O(log (4R/3)) ?

Comment: thang is correct. I made a mistake @bysreg. Correcting my answer

Comment: @thang can you please confirm if my last equation is correct and if there is a way to reduce the RHS

Comment: well, one thing that will help is to suppose n = 4^p for some integer p for simplicity.  then observe that you can only unroll p times before you end up with T(1).  so T(4^p) = 3 T(4^(p-1)) + f(n) = ... = 3^p T(1) + p f(n) and substitute p = log(n)/log(4).  and now in the general case, observe that for any n there is always p1 and p2 such that 4^p1 < n < 4^p2.

Comment: @thang can you answer the question in new post? because i dont really get your explanation