# Search element in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I recently sat in an interview and I was asked this question:

> Given a 2d array of integers, where:
>
> - Every row is sorted from left to right.
> - Every column is sorted from top to bottom.
>
> What is the best algorithm for finding the position of an element x?

I was happy, as I had done this before, and this was my answer:

> Start at the top right position.
>
> If e at that position is greater than x,then definitely, all elements
>   of that column are greater than x and we move one column back.
>
> If e at that position is less than x, then definitely all the elements
>   behind e are less than x and all elements after e are greater than x
>   and so we move one row down,
>
> If e==x, we stop or we keep doing this,until we hit the left boundary
>   or the bottom boundary and if we hit a boundary before we find
>   e==x,then the 2d array does not contain that element.

Clearly, the time complexity of this method is **O(n) for nXn matrix**, but the interviewer  insisted on a logrithmic approach, and I was unable to reach anywhere near **O(log n)**.

My question is, can it be done in **O(log n)**?

Comment: I think someone answered this already in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457792/given-a-2d-array-sorted-in-increasing-order-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done, you just need to do a binary search.

```
public int searchMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A, int B) {
    int row, col;
    int m, n;
    if (A == null)
        return 0;
    m = A.size();
    if (m == 0)
        return 0;
    n = A.get(0).size();
    row = 0;
    col = n - 1;
    while (checkBound(row, col, m, n)) {
        if (B == A.get(row).get(col))
            return 1;
        int num = A.get(row).get(col);

        if (B < num)
            col--;
        else if (B > num)
            row++;
    }
    return 0;
}

public boolean checkBound(int row, int col, int m, int n) {
    return (row >= 0 && row < m && col >= 0 && col < n);
```

}

Comment: Isn't this O(m+n) where A is an m by n matrix?