# Find the Maximum Element in any SubMatrix of Matrix

Tags: algorithm

I am giving a Matrix of `N x M`. For a Submatrix of Length `X` which starts at position `(a, b)` i have to find the largest element present in a Submatrix.

**My Approach:**

1. Do as the question says:
   Simple 2 loops

> ```
>    for(i in range(a, a + x))
>    for(j in range(b, b + x)) max = max(max,A[i][j]) // N * M
> ```

A little Advance:

```
 1. Make a segment tree for every i in range(0, N)
 2. for i in range(a, a + x) query(b, b + x)    // N * logM
```

Is there any better solution having O(log n) complexity only ?

Comment: If you can sort each column and each row, you could use that approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457792/given-a-2d-array-sorted-in-increasing-order-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom

Comment: O(1) complexity is possible. Just search Internet for "Two-Dimensional Range Minimum Queries". And for fixed `X` there is a simple O(1) time algorithm with O(MN) preprocessing.

Answer (score 6):

A Sparse Table Algorithm Approach
:- `<O( N x M x log(N) x log(M)) , O(1)>`. 
**Precomputation Time** - `O( N x M x log(N) x log(M))`
**Query Time** - `O(1)`

For understanding this method you should have knowledge of finding RMQ using sparse Table Algorithm for one dimension.

We can use 2D Sparse Table Algorithm for finding Range Minimum Query.

**What we do in One Dimension:-**
we preprocess **RMQ** for sub arrays of length `2^k` using dynamic programming. We will keep an array `M[0, N-1][0, logN]` where `M[i][j]` is the index of the minimum value in the sub array starting at `i`.
For calculating `M[i][j]` we must search for the minimum value in the first and second half of the interval. It’s obvious that the small pieces have `2^(j – 1)` length, so the pseudo code for calculation this is:-

```
if (A[M[i][j-1]] < A[M[i + 2^(j-1) -1][j-1]])
    M[i][j] = M[i][j-1]
else 
    M[i][j] = M[i + 2^(j-1) -1][j-1]
```

Here `A` is actual array which stores values.Once we have these values preprocessed, let’s show how we can use them to calculate **RMQ(i, j)**. The idea is to select two blocks that entirely cover the interval `[i..j]` and  find the minimum between them. Let `k = [log(j - i + 1)]`. For computing **RMQ(i, j)** we can use the following formula:-

```
if (A[M[i][k]] <= A[M[j - 2^k + 1][k]])
    RMQ(i, j) = A[M[i][k]]
else 
    RMQ(i , j) = A[M[j - 2^k + 1][k]]
```

**For 2 Dimension :-**
Similarly We can extend above rule for 2 Dimension also , here we preprocess **RMQ** for sub matrix of length `2^K, 2^L` using dynamic programming & keep an array `M[0,N-1][0, M-1][0, logN][0, logM]`. Where `M[x][y][k][l]` is the index of the minimum value in the sub matrix starting at `[x , y]` and having length `2^K, 2^L` respectively.
pseudo code for calculation `M[x][y][k][l]` is:-

```
M[x][y][i][j] = GetMinimum(M[x][y][i-1][j-1], M[x + (2^(i-1))][y][i-1][j-1], M[x][y+(2^(j-1))][i-1][j-1], M[x + (2^(i-1))][y+(2^(j-1))][i-1][j-1])
```

Here `GetMinimum` function will return the index of minimum element from provided elements. Now we have preprocessed, let's see how to calculate **RMQ(x, y, x1, y1)**. Here `[x, y]` starting point of sub matrix and `[x1, y1]` represent end point of sub matrix means bottom right point of sub matrix. Here we have to select four sub matrices blocks that entirely cover `[x, y, x1, y1]` and find minimum of them. Let `k = [log(x1 - x + 1)]` & `l = [log(y1 - y + 1)]`. For computing **RMQ(x, y, x1, y1)** we can use following formula:-

```
RMQ(x, y, x1, y1) = GetMinimum(M[x][y][k][l], M[x1 - (2^k) + 1][y][k][l], M[x][y1 - (2^l) + 1][k][l], M[x1 - (2^k) + 1][y1 - (2^l) + 1][k][l]);
```

**pseudo code for above logic:-**

```
// remember Array 'M' store index of actual matrix 'P' so for comparing values in GetMinimum function compare the values of array 'P' not of array 'M' 
SparseMatrix(n , m){ // n , m is dimension of matrix.
    for i = 0 to 2^i <= n:
        for j = 0 to 2^j <= m:
            for x = 0 to x + 2^i -1 < n :
                for y = 0 to y + (2^j) -1 < m:
                    if i == 0 and j == 0:
                        M[x][y][i][j] = Pair(x , y) // store x, y
                    else if i == 0:
                        M[x][y][i][j] = GetMinimum(M[x][y][i][j-1], M[x][y+(2^(j-1))][i][j-1])
                    else if j == 0:
                        M[x][y][i][j] = GetMinimum(M[x][y][i-1][j], M[x+ (2^(i-1))][y][i-1][j])
                    else 
                        M[x][y][i][j] = GetMinimum(M[x][y][i-1][j-1], M[x + (2^(i-1))][y][i-1][j-1], M[x][y+(2^(j-1))][i-1][j-1], M[x + (2^(i-1))][y+(2^(j-1))][i-1][j-1]);
}
RMQ(x, y, x1, y1){
    k = log(x1 - x + 1)
    l = log(y1 - y + 1)
    ans = GetMinimum(M[x][y][k][l], M[x1 - (2^k) + 1][y][k][l], M[x][y1 - (2^l) + 1][k][l], M[x1 - (2^k) + 1][y1 - (2^l) + 1][k][l]);
    return P[ans->x][ans->y] // ans->x represent Row number stored in ans and similarly ans->y represent column stored in ans
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, this pseudo code is correct? I've implemented the same in c++, but it didn't work well, and I got wrong answers. I think there is something not right.

Comment: Ho do you implemented GetMinimum function

Comment: This GetMinimum function was to find maximum of the elements. First I was storing the indices, then I got somehow errors, and then I stored the original values from the matrix. Now the problem is solved. Thanks for the awesome answer.

Comment: The query time will be O(logN + logM) if in every query you compute the values of `k` and `l`. It would be O(1) when we precompute the log as well. Nice answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code in c++, for the pseudo code given by @Chapta, as was requested by some user.

```
int M[1000][1000][10][10];
int **matrix;

void precompute_max(){
    for (int i = 0 ; (1<<i) <= n; i += 1){
        for(int j = 0 ; (1<<j) <= m ; j += 1){
            for (int x = 0 ; x + (1<<i) -1 < n; x+= 1){
                for (int y = 0 ;  y + (1<<j) -1 < m; y+= 1){
                    if (i == 0 and j == 0)
                        M[x][y][i][j] = matrix[x][y]; // store x, y
                    else if (i == 0)
                        M[x][y][i][j] = max(M[x][y][i][j-1], M[x][y+(1<<(j-1))][i][j-1]);
                    else if (j == 0)
                        M[x][y][i][j] = max(M[x][y][i-1][j], M[x+ (1<<(i-1))][y][i-1][j]);
                    else 
                        M[x][y][i][j] = max(M[x][y][i-1][j-1], M[x + (1<<(i-1))][y][i-1][j-1], M[x][y+(1<<(j-1))][i-1][j-1], M[x + (1<<(i-1))][y+(1<<(j-1))][i-1][j-1]);
                    // cout << "from i="<<x<<" j="<<y<<" of length="<<(1<<i)<<" and length="<<(1<<j) <<"max is: " << M[x][y][i][j] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int compute_max(int x, int y, int x1, int y1){
    int k = log2(x1 - x + 1);
    int l = log2(y1 - y + 1);
    // cout << "Value of k="<<k<<" l="<<l<<endl;
    int ans = max(M[x][y][k][l], M[x1 - (1<<k) + 1][y][k][l], M[x][y1 - (1<<l) + 1][k][l], M[x1 - (1<<k) + 1][y1 - (1<<l) + 1][k][l]);
    return ans;
}
```

This code first precomputes, the 2 dimensional sparse table, and then queries it in constant time.
Additional info: the sparse table stores the maximum element and not the indices to the maximum element.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there can be no O(logn approach) as the matrix follows no order. However, if you have an order such that every row is sorted in ascending from left to right and every column is sorted ascending from up to down, then you know that A[a+x][b+x] (bottom-right cell of the submatrix) is the largest element in that submatrix. Thus, finding the maximum takes O(1) time once the matrix is sorted. However, sorting the matrix, if not already sorted, will cost O(NxM log{NxM})