# Maximum element in all AXB sub matrices of NXM matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to find maximum element of any sub matrix AXB from a matrix NXM. I implemented sparse tree method. But I was unable to optimise this. Actually I need to solve range queries, so I need to optimize the code. On doing pre-computation, for any N,M values it takes O(NMlog(N)log(M)) time complexity. How can I improve this to (N*M). Here is my code for precomputation

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
  for(int j=0; j<m;j++)
        cin>>arr[i][j];

for(int i=0; pow(2,i) <= n; i++)
        for(int j=0; pow(2,j) <= m; j++)
            for(int x=0; x + pow(2,i)-1 < n; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y + pow(2,j) -1 < m; y++)
                {
                    i=(int)i;
                    j=(int)j;
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                            M[x][y][i][j] = arr[x][y]; 
                    else if (i == 0)
                            M[x][y][i][j] = maxi(2,M[x][y][i][j-1], M[x][(int)(y+pow(2,(j-1)))][i][j-1]);
                    else if (j == 0)
                            M[x][y][i][j] = maxi(2,M[x][y][i-1][j], M[(int)(x+ pow(2,(i-1)))][y][i-1][j]);
                    else 
                            M[x][y][i][j] = maxi(4,M[x][y][i-1][j-1], M[(int)(x + pow(2,(i-1)))][y][i-1][j-1], M[x][(int)(y+pow(2,(j-1)))][i-1][j-1], M[(int)(x + pow(2,(i-1)))][(int)(y+pow(2,(j-1)))][i-1][j-1]);
                }
```

For input x,y,x1,y1

```
 k = log(x1 - x + 1);
 l = log(y1 - y + 1);
 int max_element = max(4,M[x][y][k][l], M[(int)(x1 - pow(2,k) + 1)][y][k][l], M[x][(int)(y1 - pow(2,l) + 1)][k][l], M[(int)(x1 - pow(2,k) + 1)][(int)(y1 - pow(2,l) + 1)][k][l]);
```

How can Improve performance of this code. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not better than `O(N*M*Log(N)*Log(M))`, but it is better than your implementation.

By seeing your order of execution of `for` loops and accessing of array `M`, There will be too many Memory jump and cache miss which cause program to run slow.

Example:-

See the time taken by following Loops:

```
int M[1000][1000][11][11];
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j <= 10 ; j++){
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 1000 ; x++){
            for(int y = 0 ;  y < 1000 ; y++){
                M[x][y][i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above execution take ***1.9 sec***.

```
int M[11][11][1000][1000];
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j <= 10 ; j++){
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 1000 ; x++){
            for(int y = 0 ;  y < 1000 ; y++){
                M[i][j][x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this one takes only ***0.2 sec***. So always try to write loops such that there is sequential access of memory.

For more details you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra).

So if you change your code in following manner it will be much more faster:

```
M[Log(n)][Log(m)][n][m];
for(int i=0; (1<<i) <= n; i++)
        for(int j=0; (1<<j) <= m; j++)
            for(int x=0; x + (1<<i)-1 < n; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y + (1<<j) -1 < m; y++)
                {
                    i=(int)i;
                    j=(int)j;
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                            M[i][j][x][y] = arr[x][y]; 
                    else if (i == 0)
                            M[i][j][x][y] = maxi(2,M[i][j-1][x][y], M[i][j-1][x][(y+(1<<(j-1)))]);
                    else if (j == 0)
                            M[i][j][x][y] = maxi(2,M[i-1][j][x][y], M[i-1][j][(x+ (1<<(i-1)))][y]);
                    else 
                            M[i][j][x][y] = maxi(4,M[i-1][j-1][x][y], M[i-1][j-1][(x + (1<<(i-1)))][y], M[i-1][j-1][x][(y+(1<<(j-1)))], M[i-1][j-1][(x + (1<<(i-1)))][(y+(1<<(j-1)))]);
                }
```

And one more optimization can be done, if you are calculation `log()` too many times (i.e order of 10^5 or greater) than you can use `31-__builtin_clz()` instead  of `log()`.

```
k = 31-__builtin_clz(x1 - x + 1);
l = 31-__builtin_clz(y1 - y + 1);
int max_element = max(4,M[k][l][x][y], M[k][l][(x1 - (1<<k) + 1)][y], M[k][l][x][(y1 - (1<<l) + 1)], M[k][l][(x1 - (1<<k) + 1)][(y1 - (1<<l) + 1)]);
```

Comment: Thanks but the algo you have modified is giving wrong answers to every x,y,x1,y1. Also after this operation, my array is getting altered. Why this is happening?

Comment: I haven't change your algorithm. I just changes the access of array element so that it can be faster. Don't copy paste this code this might give error.

Comment: I have implemented what you have specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627085/find-the-maximum-element-in-a-matrix link. Here is the link to my code https://ideone.com/ntfXKB. Can u please tell where I am wrong.

Comment: You have copied code before edit that was wrong. Now just use above new code this will give correct output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. But it fails when the case is x1=1, y1=3, x2=1, y2= 4. The output for the given matrix should be 4 but it is giving 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me.