# Find if a value exists in the 2D array using Binary search.If possible trace 43 in matrix table.

Tags: php, algorithm, search, matrix, binary

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbj90.jpg)

Matrix is in the form of

```
10 | 13 | 43 | 61 | 67 | 83      
14 | 24 | 47 | 71 | 3  | 94  
22 | 33 | 51 |82  | 88 | 96  
27 | 41 | 52 | 84 | 92 | 99  
38 | 45 | 52 | 90 | 95 | 101  
105|111 |121 |133 |144 |149
```

**Find 43,60,144**

Given a 2D array with numeric values that are sorted row wise 4 column wise.Find if a value exists in the array using binary search.

I have traced it by binary search in image.
1st try:
I have traced it by  first finding the midpoint(51).After finding the first midpoint,I have divided the matrix in two parts. 1st part is  the upper half (10-51 diagonally) and 2nd is the remaining part.Can I divide the matrix in such way(1st try)?

2nd try:I have again taken a midpoint(51) and divided into lower and upper half.Upper half and lower half taken by diagonal numbers.

I am not able to find th values that are given.
Is there anyother condition through which I can find numbers:43,60,144 ?

2D array:

```
 int no[6][6]={{10,13,43,61,67,83},
  {14,24,47,71,73,94},  
  {22,33,51,82,88,96}, 
  {27,41,52,84,92,99},
  {38,45,60,90,95,101},
  {105,111,121,133,144,149}
  };
```

Comment: I am not able to see any 2D array. Can you post your actual array.if it's in array format it's really easy to do what you want.

Comment: Yes.I will post 2D array in few minutes.

Comment: @ked do you want to know "43,60,144" all of them exist or any of them exist

Comment: If any of them exists.Since all are present in matrix.,it should show all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a 2d array sorted in increasing order from left to right and top to bottom, what is the best way to search for a target number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457792/given-a-2d-array-sorted-in-increasing-order-from-left-to-right-and-top-to-bottom)

Comment: Yes,its the same,but I have tried it diagonally once.Can you trace the algorithm for me for finding 43 in matrix.It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the linear algorithm first. It is simple and has `O(n+m)` complexity. Let's simulate it step by step. We start from the left bottom corner. Then if the query number is less than the number in the current position we move up, else if it is bigger we move right.

```
10  13  43  61  67  83
14  24  47  71  73  94  
22  33  51  82  88  96 
27  41  52  84  92  99
38  45  60  90  95  101
105 111 121 133 144 149
```

We start from the left bottom corner.
`43 < 105`, so all numbers in this row will be bigger than `43`. Move up.

```
10  13  43  61  67  83
14  24  47  71  73  94  
22  33  51  82  88  96 
27  41  52  84  92  99
38  45  60  90  95  101
```

`43 > 38`, so all numbers in this column will be less than `43`. Move right.

```
13  43  61  67  83
24  47  71  73  94  
33  51  82  88  96 
41  52  84  92  99
45  60  90  95  101
```

`43 < 45`. Move up.

```
13  43  61  67  83
24  47  71  73  94  
33  51  82  88  96 
41  52  84  92  99
```

`43 > 41`. Move right.

```
43  61  67  83
47  71  73  94  
51  82  88  96 
52  84  92  99
```

`43 < 52`. Move up.

```
43  61  67  83
47  71  73  94  
51  82  88  96
```

`43 < 51`. Move up.

```
43  61  67  83
47  71  73  94
```

`43 < 47`. Move up.

```
43  61  67  83
```

`43 = 43`. Bingo!

Comment: Sir,you have traced it very well.

Comment: No,don't remove its fine.It will be useful for others.