# Search in a sorted matrix in Java

Tags: java

I need to search in a Sorted Matrix which is to be inserted using `List<List<Integer>>` arr . 
I am able to find a solution but not using `List<List>>`.

This is what i have tried but not working out

```
public class SearchMat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNextIint()) {
            arrList.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        List<List<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for(List<Integer> list : arrList){
            array.addAll(list);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you specify an example with an input and desired output?

Comment: if you take input `int` by `int` from `Scanner` how would you know when is the end of one array and the start of another?

Comment: i think this is duplicated consult this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457792/how-do-i-search-for-a-number-in-a-2d-array-sorted-left-to-right-and-top-to-botto

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following input: `10 20 15 25`
Your current code would create a 1x4 matrix like:

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-------------+
|  List (size 1)  | ---> |  List (size 4)  | ---> | 10 20 15 25 |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-------------+
```

What you would wish for should look like this:

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------+      +-------+
|  List (size 2)  | -+-> |  List (size 2)  | ---> | 10 20 |
+-----------------+  |   +-----------------+      +-------+
                     |   +-----------------+      +-------+
                     +-> |  List (size 2   | ---> | 15 25 |
                         +-----------------+      +-------+
```

You also don't have any kind of way of Sorting the input neither knowing how long should your matrix be.

**If you were assuming that the input was sorted** and that your line should only have 4 columns this would create the 2D matrix Nx**4** representation that you want:

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
while (scanner.hasNextIint()) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    matrix.add(list);
}
```

Hope this leads you in the right direction.